# Very simple matrix operation (Markov chain) in terms of Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, programming

I am trying to approach Markov chains as a use case for Quantum Computing. For this I took the simple introductory case from [Wikipedia (Markow-Kette)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markow-Kette):

- $v_0=\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0
  \end{pmatrix}$
- M=$\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0.2 & 0.8\\
  0.5 & 0 & 0.5\\
  0.1 & 0.9 & 0\\
  \end{pmatrix}$
- $v_1=v_0M$
- $v_3=v_0M^3$

As a starter/"appetizer" I implemented this situation with the following 3-liner using `Numpy` and got very straight forwardly the correct result `v3=[0.37  0.126 0.504]` which is in line with the result from the Wikipedia Site:

```
M = np.array([[0, 0.2, 0.8], [0.5, 0, 0.5], [0.1, 0.9, 0]])
v0=np.array([1,0,0])
v1=v0.dot(M)
print(v1)
v3=v0.dot(matrix_power(M, 3))
print(v3)
```

Now I'm stuck porting the whole thing to Qiskit, where I am really would be satisfied with a simulator-based solution:

```
qiskit.IBMQ.save_account('your_token', overwrite=True)
qiskit.IBMQ.load_account()
n_wires = 1
n_qubits = 1
provider = qiskit.IBMQ.get_provider('ibm-q')
backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
[...]
```

Asking Google led me to [Matrix product state simulation method](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/simulators/7_matrix_product_state_method.html), but it seems to be not obvious how to apply this to my simple problem. A simple nudge in the right direction would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made an implementation, I'm not sure whether it has advantages or how it generalizes. I hope it might steer you (or us) in the right direction.

The approach is as follows:

You have a matrix $M$, then:

1. Create a circuit with $2N=6$ qubits

   - The first 3 qubits represent 'being in state $i$' ($i$ is a state in $N$) (i.e. $|001>$ is state $0$, $|010>$ is state $1$,
     $|100>$ state $2$)
   - The last 3 qubits represent 'going to state $j$' ($j$ is a state in $N$)
2. Controlled go from state $i$ to state $j$ with probability $M_{i,j}$ *
3. Make sure to *not* go to state $j'$ when you're going to state $j$
4. Make sure the naming of states checks out (i.e. $|001>$ state $0$, $|010>$ is state $1$, $|100>$ is state $2$)
5. Repeat steps 2-4 for all $i$
6. Swap the last 3 qubits with the first 3 qubits, (in words, these were the states that you're 'going to' and now they are the state 'you are in').
7. Reset the last 3 qubits.

[The circuit now looks like this:](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/composer/files/new?initial=N4IgdghgtgpiBcICyEBOBrA9gNwAQGUAXGAB1wFpcBhaASwBt6ZcATZgNQnvRABoQAjhADOUBCADyABQCiAOQCKAQXxJcAJgB0ABgDcAHTC0wAY3oBXNrn2CY9WgCMAjJuMmbBsAHMIxXFDQsbAB9YWIyCF5cByiTKJYogDMor1xgQ1xcE3MACm1NAE51AHZ1AoBWKO0okloAenUa%2BvUASlxI3ETPTJMTAA9OqI6vbqyBjq6MrNzahqa53FnGxea2mNwRqd6Bryj1llH%2B6JTD3PyANgAWAGZy7Sd55aXHtrjWQ6OErKTDgbeDqbCADuEDIb02YEywNBx06o2hEXingAvoZDAJUDBUgIANrnAC6nhMmNSJjxhLRpjOhRKZUq1WeSzauO0%2BN4uMuFNMRw5bJZfJx5S5PJxrPZOM5RJmzV4jJlTNwuKcAqFRJFQvFyvF12FAyVKuF1Kut3usvl5oazJx6gFOrVepxOvFNvFksMIpduLthgRiutBs8vv1rq5mOEMEIftVPpBZH52tDMHDkd5njDEb9dr4IDYwmJtBIhFomDA4hAyKAA)

[image: markov step]

With this circuit, you can do the same steps as you proposed before, so in your case you have:

```
import numpy as np
M = np.array([[0, 0.2, 0.8], [0.5, 0, 0.5], [0.1, 0.9, 0]])
v0=np.array([1,0,0])
v1=v0.dot(M)
print(v1)
v2=v0.dot(np.linalg.matrix_power(M, 2))
print(v2)
v3=v0.dot(np.linalg.matrix_power(M, 3))
print(v3)
```

output:

```
[0.  0.2 0.8]
[0.18 0.72 0.1 ]
[0.37  0.126 0.504]
```

In Qiskit, this now is the following **:

```
from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit, transpile
from numpy import pi

# Inilialise registers
qreg_q = QuantumRegister(6, 'q')
creg_c = ClassicalRegister(3, 'c')

# Create Markov Step as a circuit
markov_step = QuantumCircuit(qreg_q)

# Create the Markov Step
# From state 0 to state 1 and 2
markov_step.cu3(2*np.arccos(np.sqrt(M[0,1])), pi/2, pi/2, qreg_q[0], qreg_q[4])
markov_step.ccx(qreg_q[4], qreg_q[0], qreg_q[5])
markov_step.cx(qreg_q[0], qreg_q[4])

# From state 1 to state 0 and 2
markov_step.cu3(2*np.arccos(np.sqrt(M[1,2])), pi/2, pi/2, qreg_q[1], qreg_q[5])
markov_step.ccx(qreg_q[5], qreg_q[1], qreg_q[3])
markov_step.cx(qreg_q[1], qreg_q[5])

# From state 2 to state 0 and 1
markov_step.cu3(2*np.arccos(np.sqrt(M[2,0])), pi/2, pi/2, qreg_q[2], qreg_q[3])
markov_step.ccx(qreg_q[3], qreg_q[2], qreg_q[4])
markov_step.cx(qreg_q[2], qreg_q[3])

# Swap
markov_step.swap(qreg_q[0], qreg_q[3])
markov_step.swap(qreg_q[1], qreg_q[4])
markov_step.swap(qreg_q[2], qreg_q[5])

# Initialise circuit
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qreg_q,creg_c)

# Initialise state (1,0,0)
circuit.x(0)

# Do the markov step n times
n = 3
for _ in range(n):
    for ins in markov_step:
        circuit.append(ins[0], ins[1], ins[2])
    circuit.reset(qreg_q[3:])

# Measure outcome
circuit.measure(qreg_q[:3], creg_c)
```

And you can run it by

```
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_qasm_simulator')
job = backend.run(circuit)
result = job.result()
counts = result.get_counts(circuit)

plot_histogram(counts)
```

And the output:

[image: output counts]

Which is approximately equal to the exact answers `[0.37  0.126 0.504]`.

This approach definitely isn't perfect and I'm quite sure optimizations can be made (e.g. not using 1 qubit per state, but using the full $2^N$ possible states) and I'm not sure how to go to larger state spaces. But it's the first step!

Some notes:

* note: Step 2 is not trivial. I implemented it as a controlled $X$-rotation. An $X$-rotation is (according to the [qiskit-textbook](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/circuits/3_summary_of_quantum_operations.html#Rotation-around-X-axis)) given by

\begin{equation}
R_x(\theta) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta /2) & -i \sin(\theta /2) \\
-i \sin(\theta /2) & \cos(\theta /2)
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}

and it brings the $|0>$ state to $\cos(\theta /2) |0> - i \sin(\theta /2) |1>$. Now, for example, we want the target qubit to be in state $|0>$ with probability 0.2 (when starting the target is in state 0). The probability of finding the target in state $|0>$ is $|\cos(\theta /2)|^2$ and this must be equal to $0.2$.
Thereby, it can be found that $\theta = 2 \arccos{\sqrt{0.2}}$.

** note: Implementing the circuit is a bit annoying because not all gates are available in all backends. Sometimes, you have to 'translate' the gates. A controlled $X$-rotation (CRX) is also a controlled U3 gate, where $CR_x(\theta) = CU3(\theta, \pi/2,\pi/2)$. Some backend also doesn't allow for the CU3 gate, but they do allow the multi-controlled gate `.mcu3`. In that case, just put your control qubit in a list by putting square brackets around it.